# error message not in development but rather in deployment using NHibernate version 2.1.1.4000

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I have had a look at

[Unable to load type 'NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971544/unable-to-load-type-nhibernate-bytecode-castle-proxyfactoryfactory-nhibernate)

I am also having the same error message when running the unit tests after deployment, however my application is running fine.  Even during development, I am not having any such error.

What is wrong?  Why I am having this error message when running the unit test?

The error message is as follows:

NHibernate.Bytecode.ProxyFactoryFactoryNotConfiguredException : The ProxyFactoryFactory was not configured.
Initialize 'proxyfactory.factory_class' property of the session-factory configuration section with one of the available NHibernate.ByteCode providers.
Example:
NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu
Example:
NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle
  ]]> 
  
- 
-

]]>

Connection string is web.config

```
> > <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
>     <session-factory>
>       <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2000Dialect</property>
>       <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
>       <property name="connection.connection_string">Server=localhost\SQLServer2005;Database=testDev;</property>
>       <property name='proxyfactory.factory_class'>NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory,
> NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>
>     </session-factory>   </hibernate-configuration>
```

The dll are:

I have NHIbernate version 2.1.1.4000, and I have NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle version 2.1.1.4000 ,Castle.Core 1.1.0, Castle.DynamicProxy2.dll version 2.1.1.0

Comment: What is the error? Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of NHibernate are you using? Version 3.2 comes pre-configured with a proxy factory. If you are using this version, you no longer need the proxyfactory.factory_class configuration option.

Also, if your tests are failing but not your app, then maybe the tests are not able to access the right hibernate config file. If you are doing the configuration programmatically, look at it once again to verify the proxy factor is set (if using NH < 3.2) or not set (if using NH >= 3.2) ...

Comment: I have NHIbernate version 2.1.1.4000, and I have NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle version 2.1.1.4000 ,Castle.Core 1.1.0, Castle.DynamicProxy2.dll version 2.1.1.0

Comment: You are getting the error only when the tests are run? Only in production environment or in dev as well? How is NHibernate configured? XML file or programmatically or a mix of both? Please share the configuration code. I would suggest that you edit the question with the NHibernate version as well as the answers to questions I asked. This way, others will already have all that info when they read the question. However, do comment on my answer saying you have edited your question, else I won't get a notification :)

Comment: I am having the error when the tests are run in production only.  In dev it is running without any error message.  I have provided a part of the web.config in the question part above.  NHinernate is configured using XML file and programatically.

Comment: You have posted the web.config. With a website you would run the initialization code once in App_Start. With unit tests, one would typically point to a separate hibernate.cfg.xml file that contains testing specific db details. When you are deploying, is that testing specific config file also getting copied?

Comment: The point I am making is, check your tests to see where exactly do the tests read the NHibernate config info from. Chances are its not web.config. That said, verify if the said file (which is present on you dev machine) is also present on your production machine in the relevant path. Under that file's properties (in VS), verify `Copy Local` is set to True. This might help getting the file over to the deployment server.