# NuGet: NHibernate, Castle.Core 3.0 and where is ProxyFactoryFactory?

Tags: nhibernate, nuget, castle, castle-dynamicproxy, nuget-package

I installed with NuGet the packages NHibernate and Castle.Core 3.0 for a new project. Usually we copied around the dlls manually; it is the first time I do that with NuGet.

Now I can't find out how to configure the ProxyFactoryFactory, or let's say, I can't find it. I referenced NHibernate and Castle.Core (the only dll I could find in the Castle.Core - package) within the project, and configured the following:

```
<property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">
    NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, 
    NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle
</property>
```

This leads to:

> ```
> Class Initialization method Tests.UnitTest1.MyClassInitialize threw exception.
> NHibernate.Bytecode.UnableToLoadProxyFactoryFactoryException:
> NHibernate.Bytecode.UnableToLoadProxyFactoryFactoryException: Unable
> to load type 'NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory,
> NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle' during configuration of proxy factory class.
> ```

Obviously this dll is missing, but where can I find that? There is a package in NuGet called `Castle.DynamicProxy`, but it is marked as obsolete.

p.s.: In the description of the Castle.Core 3.0 - package, it is said: ... including DynamicProxy ...

Comment: Do you get NHibernate package **AND** Castle.Core package separately?

Comment: Jep, I installed these packages separately.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The last versions of NHibernate do not require configuring a proxy factory.

An internal one is used by default and the old adapters are not part of the project anymore.

Comment: In other words: I can leave away the configurations regarding the ProxyFactoryFactory? Do you know from what NHibernate-version this is true?

Comment: That is correct. I'm not sure about the starting version, but it's this way for 3.2. It will "just work" if you install from nuget.

Comment: I see - I had to downgrade to 3.1 because of fluent nhibernate. Maybe it is not included yet in this version, had to reference ProxyFactoryFactory...

Comment: That downgrade is not a good idea. You can always recompile FNH if their most current build is for an earlier NH version (shame on FNH; it has been out for 6 months) Or you can stop using it completely and move to the new NH mapping by code.

Comment: Oh... I didn't know about NH mapping by code! Darn... on the other hand, I really like FNH, it is very intuitive - can't imagine that NH mapping by code is better right now :)