# NHibernate proxyfactory

Tags: nhibernate

I've installed `NHibernate.3.3.2.4000` via Nuget into my `MVC3` project, configured it without a `proxyfactory.factory_class`:

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>         
        <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect, NHibernate</property>
        <property name="connection.connection_string_name">db</property>
        <property name="adonet.batch_size">50</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">web</property>
        <property name="query.substitutions">true 1, false 0, yes 'Y', no 'N'</property>
        <mapping assembly="TheWorkshop.DomainModel" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

but like this I'm getting the following error:

> The following types may not be used as proxies:
>   TheWorkshop.DomainModel.Contact: method set_DateAdded should be 'public/protected virtual' or 'protected internal virtual'

Where the DateAdded property privately sets the DateAdded value

```
 public virtual DateTime DateAdded
 {
     get { return _dateAdded; }
     private set { _dateAdded = DateTime.Now; }
 }
```

I don't particularly want to make the setter public, the idea is that the DateAdded is automatically set.

I have seen posts that suggest I could set the `proxyfactory.factory_class` to

```
<property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">
    NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, 
    NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle
</property>
```

but the Nuget install didn't bring down any references to `NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle`, when I tried to `Install-Package NHibernate.Castle` it failed with

> Install failed. Rolling back...
>   Install-Package : Already referencing a newer version of 'NHibernate'.
>   At line:1 char:16
>   + Install-Package <<<<  NHibernate.Castle
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

So I guess I could down version NHibernate, but that seems wrong...
What *should* I do, a similar question [NuGet: NHibernate, Castle.Core 3.0 and where is ProxyFactoryFactory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8922999/96505) says I don't need to configure the `proxyfactory.factory_class` in newer versions

> The last versions of NHibernate do not require configuring a proxy factory.
>   An internal one is used by default and the old adapters are not part of the project anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You don't necessarily need Castle.Core unless you use the Castle.Core proxy factory like you did in the second part. NHibernate comes with it's own proxy factory by default which is what you had the first time, so I won't comment on the Castle.Core part (and I don't think it works with latest nhibernate anyway)
2. You can solve your error by telling nhibernate that you don't want to lazy load the class (which is enabled by default). How you do this will vary based on how you did your mapping.
3. You can get rid of the error by making the setter protected instead of private.
4. I don't think your setter is actually working like you think it is. unless you are actually setting that property with a value, it will never get the current date/time, in which case you might as well just set it with DateTime.Now rather than what you have. Also, when nhibernate loads that, you'll be getting the current date rather than the actual date/time it was created. You should be setting the value in the constructor, not hijacking the setter like you are.

Comment: That's got it, I removed the setter - I am setting the value in the constructor so not sure what I was thinking when I wrote the setter. Took me ages to write the question and about 5 seconds to fix!